# Match id from url using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to select facebook fbid from url in Javascript but I have error while using "(?<=fbid=)"
Links examples:

```
var Link1 = www.facebook.com/111111111111/fbid=2222222222?1111111111
var Link2 = www.facebook.com/posts/fbid=2222222222
```

I would like to get: 2222222222

When I try:

```
var fbid1 = Link1.match(/fbid=[0-9]{10,16}/);
var fbid2 = Link1.match(/(?<=fbid=)[0-9]{10,16}/);
```

for fbid1 - I got: "fbid=2222222222"

for fbid2 - I got: error, button is not working, but on regex online generators I got what I want. Why ?

How to select only fbid from this urls? (without split in next step)

Comment: Because the JavaScript regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group for the part you want.

```
var match = Link1.match(/fbid=([0-9]{10,16})/),
    fbid = null;
if(match !== null) {
    fbid = match[1];
}
```

Or

```
var match = Link1.match(/fbid=([0-9]{10,16})/),
    fbid = match !== null ? match[1] : null;
```